# forloops inside for loops in Django python

Tags: php, python, django

I have a question about Python Django.

**this is my views**

```
def index(request):
    contacts = Contact.objects.all()
    threeboxs = Threeboxes.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {'threeboxs': threeboxs, 'contacts': contacts})
```

**way we display in PHP**

```
for(k=0; k<3; k++){
some css class, i will add the K value eg:someclass_0
echo threeboxs[k].title;
echo threeboxs[k].description;
}
```

I can display Python Code like this.

```
{% for threebox in threeboxs%}     
  <h5>{{ threebox.title }}</h5>
  <p>{{ threebox.description|linebreaks }}</p>                
{% endfor %}
```

But doing it this way I cannot update the css class with loops. Then I tried this way but that did not work.

```
{% context['loop_times'] = range(0, 3) 
     for n in loop_times: %}
      {{ threebox[n].title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Can someone give me a suggestion about how I should do this?

Comment: threeboxs = Threeboxes.objects.all()[:3] ... this will give you first 3 results..

Comment: tnx. but i want to know how to loop it and add the value to css class. eg: 'for(i=0; i<2; i++)', i want to add the 'i' value to css class and then display the value of the object array.

Comment: The way of looping is same as you did above... if you like to add the value to the css class then try for loop outside the div and add the value in the css class.. {% for threebox in threeboxes %}<div class="{{threebox.title}}">Your code here</div>

Comment: tnx for the replay, that really helpful. but i don't want to add the {{threebox.title}}. i want add the loop iteration number LIKE 0 or 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cycle through some specified values as you iterate through the list, [fortunately Django has you covered with the `cycle` templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle).

```
{% for threebox in threeboxs%}     
  <h5 style="{% cycle  'class_1' 'class_2' 'class_3' %}">{{ threebox.title }}</h5>
  <p>{{ threebox.description|linebreaks }}</p>                
{% endfor %}
```

This would give you:

```
<h5 style="class_1">Title 1</h5>
<p>Body 1</p>                
<h5 style="class_2">Title 2</h5>
<p>Body 2</p>                
<h5 style="class_3">Title 3</h5>
<p>Body 3</p>                
<h5 style="class_1">Title 4</h5>
<p>Body 4</p>                
<h5 style="class_2">Title 5</h5>
<p>Body 5</p>
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{% for iter,threebox in threeboxs.items%}
```

That will give you access to the key if you need... Or even better:

```
forloop.counter
```

Check out this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for

What are you trying to do with the css class?